# Traversing a linked list of polymorphic derived type in both directions

Tags: linked-list, fortran, polymorphism, derived-types

Consider a following approach to implementing a simple neural network in Fortran : an abstract polymorphic type `layer`

```
    type, abstract :: layer
        real, allocatable :: A(:,:)
        class(layer), pointer :: nextLayer => null()
        class(layer), pointer :: prevLayer => null()
    contains
        procedure(updateLayerINTRFC), deferred :: update
    end type

    abstract interface
        subroutine updateLayerINTRFC(self)
            import :: layer
            class(layer), intent(inout) :: self
        end subroutine
    end interface
```

encapsulates universal properties all layers must have, ie. content (2d real array A), rule for updating the layer when new input is provided and pointers to neighbouring layers, both previous and next. Extending the base `layer` type are any number of specific layer types like

```
    type, extends(layer) :: layerA
        ! Weights determining the network behaviour
        real, allocatable :: W(:,:)
    contains
        procedure :: update => updateA
    end type

    ! to be located in the contains section of the module
    subroutine updateA(self)
        class(layerA), intent(inout) :: self

        ! The update rule has been simplified for clarity
        self%A = matmul(self%W,self%prevLayer%A)
    end subroutine
```

and a special kind `layerFirst` for the first layer of the network

```
    type, extends(layer) :: layerFirst
        integer :: nLayers                  ! number of layers in a network
        integer, allocatable :: nCells(:)   ! number of cells in each layer
    contains
        procedure :: forwardFull
        procedure :: update => updateFirst
    end type
```

Which serves as the handle for the entire network and describes its dimensions. Network is made up of linked list of layers which begins with instance of `layerFirst`. The list is generally heterogeneous which rules out using an array of type layer instead (I'm aware of a workaround by introducing an intermediate wrapper type, but prefer the pointer approach). A forward pass (ie. getting output from input) is performed simply by traversing the list and updating each layer

```
    subroutine forwardFull(self,input,output)
        class(layerFirst), intent(inout) :: self
        real, intent(in) :: input(self%nCells(1))
        real, intent(out) :: output(self%nCells(self%nLayers))
        class(layer), pointer :: currentLayer
        integer :: i

        self%A(:,1) = input
        currentLayer => self%nextLayer
        do i=2,self%nLayers-1
            call currentLayer%update()
            currentLayer => currentLayer%nextLayer
        end do
        call currentLayer%update
        output = reshape(currentLayer%A,shape=[self%nCells(self%nLayers)])
    end subroutine
```

Since the question is not about training the networks, the weights can be just randomly generated to give a minimal working example which compiles under gfortran-10

```
module utils
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: layer
        real, allocatable :: A(:,:)
        class(layer), pointer :: nextLayer => null()
        class(layer), pointer :: prevLayer => null()
    contains
        procedure(updateLayerINTRFC), deferred :: update
    end type

    type, extends(layer) :: layerFirst
        integer :: nLayers
        integer, allocatable :: nCells(:)
    contains
        procedure :: forwardFull
        procedure :: update => updateFirst
    end type

    type, extends(layer) :: layerA
        real, allocatable :: W(:,:)
    contains
        procedure :: update => updateA
    end type

    abstract interface
        subroutine updateLayerINTRFC(self)
            import :: layer
            class(layer), intent(inout) :: self
        end subroutine
    end interface

contains

    ! ignore this, first layer does not need to be updated
    subroutine updateFirst(self)
        class(layerFirst), intent(inout) :: self
        ! Do nothing
    end subroutine


    subroutine updateA(self)
        class(layerA), intent(inout) :: self

        ! the update rule has been simplified for clarity
        self%A = matmul(self%W,self%prevLayer%A)
    end subroutine


    subroutine forwardFull(self,input,output)
        class(layerFirst), intent(inout) :: self
        real, intent(in) :: input(self%nCells(1))
        real, intent(out) :: output(self%nCells(self%nLayers))
        class(layer), pointer :: currentLayer
        integer :: i

        self%A(:,1) = input
        currentLayer => self%nextLayer
        do i=2,self%nLayers-1
            call currentLayer%update()
            currentLayer => currentLayer%nextLayer
        end do
        call currentLayer%update
        output = reshape(currentLayer%A,shape=[self%nCells(self%nLayers)])
    end subroutine


    function newLayerA(ncurr,nprev) result(res)
        type(layerA) :: res
        integer, intent(in) :: ncurr, nprev

        allocate(res%A(ncurr,1))
        allocate(res%W(ncurr,nprev))
        call random_number(res%A)
    end function


    function newNetwork() result(net)
        type(layerFirst), target :: net
        class(layer), pointer :: currentLayer
        integer :: i

        ! network dimensions are hardcoded for simplicity
        net%nLayers = 4
        net%nCells = [784,128,64,10]

        allocate(net%A(net%nCells(1),1))
        allocate(net%nextLayer, source=newLayerA(net%nCells(2),net%nCells(1)))
        currentLayer => net%nextLayer
        currentLayer%prevLayer => net ! is net missing a target attribute
        do i=2,net%nLayers-1
            allocate(currentLayer%nextLayer, source=newLayerA(net%nCells(i+1),net%nCells(i)))
            currentLayer%nextLayer%prevLayer => currentLayer
            currentLayer => currentLayer%nextLayer
        end do
    end function
end module

program test
    use utils
    implicit none

    type(layerFirst) :: net
    real :: input(784,1), output(10,1)

    call random_number(input)
    net = newNetwork()
    call net%forwardFull(input,output)
    print '(" Most likely match : ", I0)', maxloc(output,1)-1
end program
```

However, this does not seems to correctly associate second layers `prevLayer` pointer to the first layer, at least not consistently. All others can be simply checked and only problem is with the one marked "not ok" on the diagram

```
                                 Ok                      Ok                      Ok                                  
             ┌────────────────┐      ┌────────────────┐      ┌────────────────┐      ┌────────────────┐              
             │type(layerFirst)├─────►│  type(layerA)  ├─────►│  type(layerA)  ├─────►│  type(layerA)  ├─────►  Null()
             │     :: net     │      │                │      │                │      │                │              
             │   784  cells   │      │   128  cells   │      │    64 cells    │      │    10 cells    │              
Null() ◄─────┤                │◄─────┤                │◄─────┤                │◄─────┤                │              
             └────────────────┘      └────────────────┘      └────────────────┘      └────────────────┘              
                               Not ok                    Ok                      Ok
```

For example, calling `print*, shape(net%nextLayer%prevLayer%A)` from the main program produces incorrect output `3784704  0` instead of `784  1` as `print*, shape(net%A)` would. This sometimes (with annoying inconsistency) causes the matrix multiplication in `updateA` for the second layer to crash the program.

Are there some esoteric rules pertaining to linking different types of the same general class? Have I made a mistake (probably in the function `newNetwork`) or is this a compiler issue?

**UPDATE** : ifx error message points in the direction of the line `allocate(net%nextLayer, source=newLayerA(net%nCells(2),net%nCells(1)))` claiming `Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation`, but I'm not sure what to make of it. Full message goes

```
==11782==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x4a7ae6 in utils_mp_newnetwork_ /home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/src/neco.f90:93:13
    #1 0x4aad5f in MAIN__ /home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/src/neco.f90:107:11
    #2 0x40a768 in main (/home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/a.out+0x40a768) (BuildId: 344b775a27909a7ac2f3797db049781f62dcc8f5)
    #3 0x7f5a69821c86 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-CVJwZb/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310
    #4 0x40a619 in _start (/home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/a.out+0x40a619) (BuildId: 344b775a27909a7ac2f3797db049781f62dcc8f5)

  Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation
    #0 0x418046 in malloc (/home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/a.out+0x418046) (BuildId: 344b775a27909a7ac2f3797db049781f62dcc8f5)
    #1 0x50a454 in _mm_malloc (/home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/a.out+0x50a454) (BuildId: 344b775a27909a7ac2f3797db049781f62dcc8f5)
    #2 0x4aeb23 in do_alloc_copy for_alloc_copy.c
    #3 0x4addbd in do_for_alloc_copy for_alloc_copy.c
    #4 0x4a40fc in utils_mp_newnetwork_ /home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/src/neco.f90:88:9
    #5 0x4aad5f in MAIN__ /home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/src/neco.f90:107:11
    #6 0x40a768 in main (/home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/a.out+0x40a768) (BuildId: 344b775a27909a7ac2f3797db049781f62dcc8f5)
    #7 0x7f5a69821c86 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-CVJwZb/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /home/pavel/Dokumenty/meteorologie/otazka/src/neco.f90:93:13 in utils_mp_newnetwork_
Exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is this line in the main program:

```
    net = newNetwork()
```

and this one in the `newNetwork()` function:

```
        currentLayer%prevLayer => net ! is net missing a target attribute
```

`net` is declared as a local object in `newNetwork()`, which is different from `net` declared in the main program. This means that you are pointing to something that disapears once the function returns.

There are several solutions to make it working:

- declare `newNetwork()` as a type bound procedure of your `firstLayer` class and call it from the main program:
  `call net%netNetwork()`
- change object to pointers. In the main:
  `type(layerFirst), pointer :: net`
  `net => newNetwork()`
  In the function:
  `type(layerFirst), pointer :: net`
  `allocate(net)`
  The `net` pointer of the function will disappear as well, but the `net` pointer of main will eventually point to the same memory area.

Maybe there are other issues, but this one should be fixed first.

Comment: you are correct, implementing your first suggestion was easy and effective, good catch